# CHttpException when trying to submit a form with a captcha

Tags: php, yii, captcha

I'm new to the yii framework and I am trying to execute a php application in my local zwamp environment. The application works correctly in a production environnent.

The Error I receive is after filling the form and trying to submit it. The captcha doesn't validate and I get the following error in the logs:

```
2014/11/10 10:23:17 [error] [exception.CHttpException.404] exception 'CHttpException' with message 'The system cannot find the action « undefined » that is requested.' in D:\Users\....\web\CController.php:483
Stack trace:
#0 D:\Users\...\web\CController.php(270): CController->missingAction('undefined')
#1 D:\Users\...\web\CWebApplication.php(282): CController->run('undefined')
#2 D:\Users\...\web\CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController('site/undefined')
#3 D:\Users\...\base\CApplication.php(180): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#4 D:\Users\....\index.php(23): CApplication->run()
#5 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/appname/site/undefined
HTTP_REFERER=http://localhost:92/appname/site/form
```

How can I fix this or identify which action is causing the problem?

**EDIT: problem seems to come from here : the verification code does not match the image displayed.. **

```
/**
 * Gets the verification code.
 * @param boolean $regenerate whether the verification code should be regenerated.
 * @return string the verification code.
 */
public function getVerifyCode($regenerate=false)
{
    if($this->fixedVerifyCode !== null)
        return $this->fixedVerifyCode;

    $session = Yii::app()->session;
    $session->open();
    $name = $this->getSessionKey();
    if($session[$name] === null || $regenerate)
    {
        $session[$name] = $this->generateVerifyCode();
        $session[$name . 'count'] = 1;
    }


    $message = $session[$name];
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";


    return $session[$name];
}
```

what could be the issue?

Comment: Do you use a [CCaptchaAction](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CCaptchaAction)?

Comment: yes I am using CCaptchaAction

Comment: please show the code where you create CCaptcha widget and validation rule.

Comment: Added relevant code. The $session[$name] value doesn't match the image displayed

Comment: Action id is not resolved.Post your controller/view/config code here to understand your issue better

Comment: Post up your server config. Looks like a rewrite issue to me.

Answer (score 0):

Ayrad, the error message is quite ambiguous saying like, "...action « undefined ».....", in general Yii 404 errors specifies name of it (for example, "...Unable to resolve the request "ABC XYZ ...." ).

These kind of errors depend on many things, like, was  engine rewrite was enabled, how is your .htacess. At least, how is your "URLManager" looks in your Config.

So, my answer is from my experience from the problem which I faced earlier.  Their are some broken links in my CSS file, so  I got error likes this,

```css
[error] [exception.CHttpException.404] exception 'CHttpException' with message 'The system is unable to find the requested action "undefined".' in C:\wamp\yii\framework\web\CController.php:484
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\yii\framework\web\CController.php(271): CController->missingAction('undefined')
#1 C:\wamp\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(283): CController->run('undefined')
#2 C:\wamp\yii\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(142): CWebApplication->runController('site/undefined')
#3 C:\wamp\yii\framework\base\CApplication.php(162): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#4 C:\wamp\www\index.php(27): CApplication->run()
#5 {main}
REQUEST_URI=/site/undefined
HTTP_REFERER=http://localhost/site/index
```

I checked my main layout and find out this buggy javascript function causes that error:

```js
$(".shortcuts").each(function(){
        var cacheImage = document.createElement('img');
        cacheImage.src = $(this).attr('rel');
        cache.push(cacheImage);
        });
```

It was suppose to preload shortcuts images on the bootstrap navbar. so that fixed the problem. Hope this helps. if not, please try to post extra details.

Answer (score 0):

Error logs show clearly what this is about,

```
REQUEST_URI=/appname/site/undefined
```

this shows that somehow you generated a url like that and when it was trying to resolve using that, it faild (I think it's your forms url)

you have to share to view that made this form, otherwise we can't help you

Comment: this is not an answer, better you added this as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If this code working correctly in production environment. Then the issue may be due to mismatch of database or main.php. I think, this error is due to not getting the site action correctly. check that, the requesting URL is given correctly.